# New to Javascript - changing style of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So based on the value of a boolean, I want certain tabs in my sidebar to display/ hide when the page loads.

```js
var someVar = true;

function show_ifTrue() {
    if (Boolean(someVar) == true) {
        document.getElementById('x').style.display = 'block'; 
        console.log("I CHANGED IT");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('x').style.background = 'red';
    }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 50;
}
#tab {
    display: block;
}
#x {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#" id="tab"> Cats </a>
    <a href="#" id="x" onpageshow="show_ifTrue();"> Dogs</a>
</div>
```

I have tried everything from taking out the display from `.sidebar a{...}`  and giving each tab its own display property, using `!important`, changing in JS using `style.cssText` or setting attribute, I just can't get it to change the display.

Comment: And where does the `onpageshow` event come from? Are you using jQuery mobile or something similar ?

Comment: @adeneo http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onpageshow.asp

Comment: Note that onpageshow is only allowed in the "body" element.

Comment: Better not call the `Boolean` constructor here - try using `!!someVar === true` as a comparison instead.

Comment: @Midas - oh, I see, that's the `window.onpageshow` event, that can be attached inline to the body, but not an anchor, and is generally a horrible event to use for things like this. I actually assumed it was the event with the same name from jQuery mobile, but even that event was deprecated and removed in later versions, because it was ... horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the color, you have to call the function first, but you are never calling it, since [**`onpageshow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow) could only be added to `<body>`, so you could move it there - `<body onpageshow='...'>`. Or, if you still want to deal only with the div itself, do it onload:

```
window.onload=function(){
    show_ifTrue();
}
```

This way too could also use your pageshow:

```
window.onpageshow=function(){
    show_ifTrue();
}
```

Also, you don't need Boolean prefix in your function, just `someVar == true`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this being an interactive overlay menu changes anything but I tried calling the function inside the sidebar div and it still does not work. I don't actually want the color change, I put that there as an indicator that the function ran in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, only window.onpageshow works (maybe by .onload call the content didn't load yet? not sure) But it works, thanks!

Comment: @nicael How so is it not called when the page is cached? That's new for me. I think it's just an error on W3Schools.

Comment: @Midas I also thought it was a error because has never encountered it, though OP proves that wrong...

Comment: @nicael No, you said: "the onload even isn't called if the page is cached"

Comment: @Midas Sure, I've seen it somewhere but never experienced so it's likely OP's mistake. Never mind though, removed that confusing comment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing the css closing braket for `#tab` (EDIT: OP edited this, but it could also have been part of the issue). Also, you might want to use `window.onload`, or `onpageshow` on the body element — it's the only element that it will work on. With that fixed, here's a working example:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    show_ifTrue();
}

var someVar = true;

function show_ifTrue() {
    if (someVar === true) {
        document.getElementById('x').style.display = 'block'; 
        console.log('I CHANGED IT');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('x').style.background = 'red';
    }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 50;
 }

#tab {
    display: block;
}

#x {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#" id="tab"> Cats </a>
    <a href="#" id="x"> Dogs</a>
</div>
```

I hope that helps!